# DJANGO HTML and Python - How to display list in horizontal view with proper spacing

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-views

I am trying to make a personal website to track my list of rentals so that everywhere i go, i can view who are still not paid. (btw, i am not an IT person.. just trying to be techie and see how far i can go with it..)

i have a csv file, it contains the following information.
serial number, name, address, age, monthly_rent, unpaid_months, total_unpaid

i am able to show it in the html, but it not aligned properly.

Here's what i tried

HTML

```
<h1>RENT {% for dt in data %} <p> {{ dt }} </p> {% endfor %} </h1>
```

VIEWS.PY

```
out = [] * 4
count = 0
rental_list = open('rent/static/rentals.txt', 'r')

while True:
    line = rental_list.readline()
    if not line:
        break

    display = line.replace(',', '      ')
    if not count == 0:
        out.append(display)
    count += 1
rental_list.close()

return render(request, 'main.html', {'data' : out})
```

i have two records as test.
it shows like this unfortunately

> 0001 AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF

> 0002 GGG HHH III JJJ KKK LLL

I wanted it to be flexible, like in a specific coordinates like this when i add the headers.

SN     NAME         ADDRESS             RENT          UNPAID(MOS)        TOTAL UNPAID

1. AAA.         BBB                 CCC           DDD                EEE            <button>

If anyone can guide me or show me tutorials for examples would be great, as i want to understand also how it can be achieved for my future things to do :)

Comment: Could you clearify? Do you want to reorder? Or do you want to restyle it as your title indicates?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to reach what you want. The fast one for your case is HTML table. First you will need context built in other way, something like:

```
def your_view(request):
    context = {
        'headers': [],
        'table_data': []
    }

    with open('rent/static/rentals.txt', 'r') as f:
       context['headers'] = f.readline().split(',')
       for line in f:
           context['table_data'] += [line.split(',')]

    return render(request, 'main.html', context)
```

And then in your template you can define html table which will handle intending

```
<table>
  <tr>
    {% for header in headers %}
    <th>{{ header }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% for row in table_data %}
  <tr>
    {% for cell in row %}
    <td>{{ cell }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

With this approach it won't be depending on amount columns of your file. I tested it for file with this structure:

```
ID,Amount,Qty
1,23,100
2,20,200
3,15,100
```

As I understood from code in the question it's something what you have. That I received after page render:

[image]